# Is the problem well conditioned or not $x=1-e^p$.

Tags: proof-verification, numerical-methods, condition-number

For large numbers $|p|\gg1$ we want to compute $x=1-e^p$.

Is the problem for $|p|\gg 1$ well conditioned.

We have
$$\kappa = \frac{\|x'\|}{\|x\|}\cdot \|p\|=\frac{\|-e^p\|}{\|1-e^p\|}\cdot \|p\|$$

If $p>0$ we have
$$\kappa=\frac{e^p}{-1+e^p} \cdot p=\frac{pe^p}{e^p-1}\approx p$$ so the problem is ill conditioned.

If $p<0$ 
$$\kappa=\frac{e^p}{1-e^p}\cdot -p=\frac{-p e^p}{1-e^p}\approx -p e^p \to 0 ~(p\to-\infty),$$
so the problem is well conditioned.
I am not sure if my work is correct.

Comment: It's when $|p|\ll 1$ that the problem is ill-conditioned. Then $e^p\approx 1$ and so the subtraction loses precision.

Comment: We are assuming $p$ is large in absolute value always. Be it negative or positive.

Comment: Then the problem is not ill-conditioned.

Comment: I fixed the obvious error in the derivative but otherwise I still have a large condition number for positive $p$.

Comment: The function $$y=\frac{\left|-e^x\right|}{\left|1-e^x\right|}\left|x\right|$$ explodes at $+\infty$ and tends to $0$ at $-\infty$

Comment: I think you had better define what you mean by an ill-conditioned problem.

Comment: What other definition is there? Large condition number= ill conditioned

Comment: It seems to me that a function $f(p)$ is ill-conditioned if the condition number is large relative to $|f(p)|$, which is not the case here.

Comment: I have searched all over the internet, but I can't find a definition of what it means for a function $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ to be ill-conditioned. It is a term usually reserved for multi-variable systems of equations. But from a numerical analysis standpoint, $1-e^p$ is easy to compute accurately (i.e. to a high relative precision) when $|p|\gg 1$, but when $|p|\ll 1$ the naive computation $1-e^p$ loses relative precision disastrously.

Comment: Not my  university but here's an example https://www.mathematik.tu-dortmund.de/lsviii/new/media/veranstaltungen/wise1213/numerik/kap0_1.pdf

We also did this with $f(x)=x/2$, $\sqrt x$, $f(a_1,a_2)=a_1+a_2$ etc..